# Progress bar for Python Script in HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, progress-bar

I've been working on a project running an NMAP scan in a web app using flask and displaying the results back to the UI. The NMAP scan seems to take a while to run. Can anyone tell me how I can add a progress bar to the HTML UI?

The script I am running Discovery1.py

```
    import nmap
    import pandas as pd

    ns = nmap.PortScanner()
    ns.scan('10.0.0.0/24')
    print(ns._scan_result)
    print(ns.csv(),file=open('results.csv','w'))
    df = pd.read_csv("results.csv", delimiter=";")
    df.to_csv("results.csv", index=None)
```

And the section of the HTML page Network.html cannot be displayed here for some odd reason. How can I achieve this and display in the HTML page.

Comment: The progressbar should be made in HTML/CSS/JavaScript. If you want it to display correct progress, you need to expose a function on the server which will be able to return the current progress. You can than use JavaScript to repeatedly ask for current progress and update the progressbar.

Comment: thanks vzone. Do you know what that looks like in python and JS?

Comment: There is a lot of code to be written. Unless there is some ready-to-use-solution available out there, but I wouldn't know about that.